# How to change the group icon in legend via Python in QGIS 2.6

Tags: python, icons, legend, qgis

I would want that group created by plugin differs from the group created by man. ;)
How to change the group icon in legend via Python in QGIS 2.6? At version 1.x I did it this way:

```
self.legendTree = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,"Legend").findChild(QTreeWidget)
currGrp=self.legendTree.currentItem()
currGrp.setIcon(0,self.setMyIcon("folder.png")
```

In pyqgis 2.6 I create group this way

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
node_group1 = root.insertGroup(0, "Group 1")
```

But how to change the icon?